# Labview: VISA resource busy only when run from subVI

Tags: labview, visa

I'm working on a labview program that will talk to box via VISA commands.  When I use the instrument assistant in the labview Instrument I/O palette as an open window, it will send and receive information perfectly.  When I close the window and try to run it within the context of the larger program (containing only that) it says that the VISA resource is busy.

I have also tried using the Open/write/close option from the Instrument I/O palette, and that also will not allow me to access the resource.   I've tried all three directly after restarting the instrument in question, so I'm pretty sure it's not actually busy.

Does anyone have experience with a similar problem, and if so how did you fix it?

Comment: How is the instrument actually connected to the computer? For a serial (or serial-via-USB) device I think this is the error you would see if another program had the port open, for example. What is the actual error code and have you tried searching ni.com for it?

Comment: Did you also restart the computer? The Instrument Assistant, if I remember correctly, can keep control of things much longer than you think.

Comment: I did restart the computer.

Comment: Can you share the block diagram of the larger program?